# Powershell redirect write-host output into new file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to send Powershell `write-host` output into new file after executing the command this command creating a blank file

```
gci -r | % { Write-Host $_.Name,$_.FullName,$_.LastWriteTime } |ft  -wrap | out-file output.txt
```

i want `FileName` and `File Full Path` and `Last Write Time` in ***output file like this***

```
170801072740IMG-20170622-WA0012 (1).jpg O:\170801072740IMG-20170622-WA0012 (1).jpg 1/14/2021 4:3
170801072756IMG-20170622-WA0014.jpg O:\170801072756IMG-20170622-WA0014.jpg 1/14/2021 4:35:22 PM
170801072818IMG-20170624-WA0028.jpg O:\170801072818IMG-20170624-WA0028.jpg 1/14/2021 4:35:22 PM
```

**Excluding Properties Names:**

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
```

also checked with antoher command which is `Write-Output`

```
gci -r | % { Write-Output $_.Name,$_.FullName,$_.LastWriteTime } >> output2.txt
```

this command is redirecting output but the output is not in **right format**

**Output file:**

```
Tuesday, March 9, 2021 1:14:42 AM
151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
O:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
Friday, March 12, 2021 8:40:15 PM
151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
O:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
Thursday, January 14, 2021 4:35:16 PM
151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
O:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
Thursday, January 14, 2021 4:35:16 PM
```

i have also tried with `Start-Transcript` method but again output is not in right format

**Start-Transcript Output file**
[image: output]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not drop `Write-Host` completely and just write the values directly to file? `gci -r | % { $_.Name,$_.FullName,$_.LastWriteTime -join ' ' } |Out-File .\path\to\file.txt`

Comment: Great thanks for Your Help

Comment: gci -r | ft  Name, FullName, LastWriteTime >> result.txt

Comment: @FletcherF1 I need only values w/o properties names ```Name``` and ```Full Name``` and ```Last Write Time```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gci -r -file | % { "$($_.Name) $($_.FullName) $($_.LastWriteTime)" >> G:\Test\Output.txt }
```

I added the -file parameter as there is no need for directories since they are included in the full path.

Sample Output:

```
Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Functions\Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1 09/20/2018 20:03:57
Get-InstalledSoftware.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Functions\Get-InstalledSoftware.ps1 05/02/2020 12:24:47
Invoke-ExerciseTimer.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Functions\Invoke-ExerciseTimer.ps1 01/19/2017 15:01:49
New-Shortcut.txt G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Functions\New-Shortcut.txt 01/15/2017 11:50:33
Test-RoboForm-Function.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Functions\Test-RoboForm-Function.ps1 02/24/2021 20:32:25
Get-DisabledServicesV1-00.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-DisabledServices\Get-DisabledServicesV1-00.ps1 01/13/2018 16:39:09
Get-DisabledServicesV2-00.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-DisabledServices\Get-DisabledServicesV2-00.ps1 01/14/2018 12:31:56
Get-WinVer-V-2-0.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-WinVer\Get-WinVer-V-2-0.ps1 03/12/2019 21:14:37
Get-WinVer-V-3-0.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-WinVer\Get-WinVer-V-3-0.ps1 12/10/2019 20:03:38
Get-WinVer-V-3-1.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-WinVer\Get-WinVer-V-3-1.ps1 12/11/2019 09:17:17
Get-WinVer-V-3-2.ps1 G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Get-WinVer\Get-WinVer-V-3-2.ps1 01/15/2020 20:53:11
```

Comment: thats what i want but did not understand that ```-file``` parameter

Comment: I recommend changing ` >> G:\Test\Output.txt }` to `} | Set-Content G:\Test\Output.txt` unless you really need to append the data. Otherwise PowerShell has to open the file to write, write data, and close the file every iteration of the `ForEach-Object` loop (once per file passed to it).